# Angular LiveTemplates on WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, ide, webstorm, live-templates

I tried to use angular live templates from [John Papa's styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), but after I restart the IDE, no templates are available. I have referred to several StackOverflow  questions and followed the instructions, but that does not seem to work. I use Ubuntu 14.04.

The directory tree looks like this:

~/WebStorm-145.1616.9/bin - this is from where I start WebStorm using './webstorm'.

~/WebStorm-145.1616.9/config/templates - this is where the live template .xml file is located. I restarted the IDE several times, nothing just happens.

Comment: Your folder with settings is most likely wrong (depends on your settings, of course; but if you have NOT specified where to store IDE settings manually ... then it is wrong). Check this link: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: @LazyOne yes, I have specified the IDE settings storage manually

Comment: That's fine -- as long as you did it correctly. 1) What folder IDE will open when you do "Help | Show Log in XXX"? 2) Do you see anything interesting there (in the log file)? 3) Where I can try and get those Live Templates (direct link to the file, please).

Comment: @LazyOne 1) ~/.WebStorm2016.1/system 2) There are a lot of files and folders here actually 3) https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/assets/webstorm-angular-live-templates/webstorm-angular-live-templates.xml?raw=true

Comment: **1)** The file with live templates is working fine (tested here in PhpStorm 2016.3.1 on Windows 10) **2)** for log files -- you need `idea.log` -- it's the current log file **3)** I do not know what exactly you have changed (the IDE settings location) but log file is stored in default folder -- so place your template file in `~/.WebStorm2016.1/config/templates` and see if it will pick it up.

Comment: **4)** You can also make a test -- create new group in Live Templates (e.g. `test1`) and create at least one dumb template in it; close IDE and check the templates folder - check where that new file will be created

Comment: @LazyOne so it happens you can browse through some live templates inside the WebStorm settings. Go to File -> Settings  -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories. There I have managed to find the above mentioned template and install it (so I will be closing the question soon), but I haven't detected any changes in my templates folder.

Comment: What plugin name exactly -- I see 2 Angular-template related plugins?

Comment: @LazyOne I browse and see just one when type 'Angular template'

Comment: I've checked both plugins and they provide different templates (at least in names). But yes -- live templates loaded through plugins are loaded dynamically from plugin resources during runtime .. so no such files in config folder will be created (unless you decide to modify them)

Comment: Plugins are: 1) Angular 2 TypeScript Live Templates 2) Angular Template